# How do i access dynamic row values in table in javascript

Tags: javascript

My Aim is to get multiple row data (product_id and its product_qnty) that is filled by the user in invoice, so i could deduct those quantities from the existing product quantities using php.
Here i am trying to get each cells data and store it in json format to pass it in controller (Laravel) php.

Here is the code;

Javascript :

```
function InvoiceDataProcess()
{

    //gets table
    var oTable = document.getElementById('rowData');

    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

    //loops through rows
    for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){

        //gets cells of current row
        var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;

        //gets amount of cells of current row
        var cellLength = oCells.length;

        //loops through each cell in current row
        for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){

            // get your cell info here
            // var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;


 cellVal = oCells[j].querySelector("input").value || oCells[j].querySelector("select").value || 0;

            console.log(cellVal);

        }
    }

    getData();

}

function getData()
{

    const arr = [document.querySelectorAll("#rowData [name=product_id]")] // cast to array to use forEach
        .map(ele => ({ "product_id": ele.value, "product_qnty": ele.closest("tr").querySelector("[name^=product_qnty]").value }));
    console.log(arr)

}
```

HTML :

```
<tbody class="text-center" id="rowData">

        <tr class="items" id="item1">
         <td>1</td>
         <td class="d-none d-print-none"><input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id"></td>
         <td><input type="text" id="product_sku"></td>
          <td><select id="products">
              <option>Select Product</option>
              </select>
          </td>
 <td class="d-print-none"><input type="number" id="total_qnty" disabled></td>
         <td><input type="number" id="product_sp" step=".01" required></td>
         <td><input type="number" id="product_qnty" name="product_qnty" required></td>
         <td><input type="number" id="gst_perc" step=".01" min="0" max="100"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="tax_perc" step=".01" min="0" max="100"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="disc_perc" step=".01" min="0" max="100"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="final_price" step=".01" required></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Inspect Element (After adding 3 rows in invoice):

```
    <tr class="items" id="item1">
       <td>1</td>
       <td class="d-none d-print-none"><input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="8"></td>
       <td><input type="text" id="product_sku"></td>
       <td><select id="products">
            <option>Select Product</option>
            <option value="Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple">Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple</option>
    <option value="Apple Watch Series 6 - Black">Apple Watch Series 6 - Black</option>
    <option value="Color check - Blue">Color check - Blue</option>
    <option value="Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey">Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey</option>
    <option value="iPad 5 - White">iPad 5 - White</option>
    <option value="Iphone 12 Mini - Blue">Iphone 12 Mini - Blue</option><option value="Iphone 12 Pro - Green">Iphone 12 Pro - Green</option>
    <option value="Iphone 12 Pro - -">Iphone 12 Pro - -</option>
    <option value="Nike Sport Plus - Yellow">Nike Sport Plus - Yellow</option>
    <option value="Puma Shoes - Brown">Puma Shoes - Brown</option>
    <option value="smart watch - -">smart watch - -</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td class="d-print-none"><input type="number" id="total_qnty" disabled=""></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="product_sp" step=".01" required=""></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="product_qnty" name="product_qnty" required="" max="2" min="1"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="gst_perc" step=".01" min="0" max="100"></td>
   <td><input type="number" id="tax_perc" step=".01" min="0" max="100"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="disc_perc" step=".01" min="0" max="100"></td>
   <td><input type="number" id="final_price" step=".01" required=""></td>
  </tr>

<!-- SECOND ROW OF INVOICE ---->

<tr class="items" id="item1">
<td>2</td>
<td class="d-none d-print-none"><input type="hidden" id="product_id2" name="product_id" value="7" class="product-id"></td>
 <td><input type="text" id="product_sku2"></td>
 <td><select id="products2" class="product-selector">
     <option>Select Product</option>
     <option value="Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple">Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple</option>
    <option value="Apple Watch Series 6 - Black">Apple Watch Series 6 - Black</option>
   <option value="Color check - Blue">Color check - Blue</option> 
   <option value="Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey">Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey</option>
  <option value="Iphone 12 Mini - Blue">Iphone 12 Mini - Blue</option> 
  <option value="Iphone 12 Pro - Green">Iphone 12 Pro - Green</option> 
 <option value="Iphone 12 Pro - -">Iphone 12 Pro - -</option>
  <option value="Nike Sport Plus - Yellow">Nike Sport Plus - Yellow</option>
  <option value="Puma Shoes - Brown">Puma Shoes - Brown</option><option value="smart watch - -">smart watch - -</option></select>
   </td>
   <td class="d-print-none"><input type="number" id="total_qnty2" disabled=""></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="product_sp2" step=".01" required="" class="product-price"></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="product_qnty2" name="product_qnty" required="" max="38" min="1" class="product-qnty"></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="gst_perc2" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-gst"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="tax_perc2" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-tax"></td>
       <td><input type="number" id="disc_perc2" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-disc"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="final_price2" step=".01" required="" class="product-total"></td>
      </tr>

<!---THIRD ROW OF INVOICE --->

<tr class="items" id="item1">
  <td>3</td>
  <td class="d-none d-print-none"><input type="hidden" id="product_id3" name="product_id" value="35" class="product-id"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="product_sku3"></td>
  <td><select id="products3" class="product-selector">
      <option>Select Product</option>
      <option value="Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple">Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple</option>
      <option value="Apple Watch Series 6 - Black">Apple Watch Series 6 - Black</option>
    <option value="Color check - Blue">Color check - Blue</option> 
     <option value="Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey">Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey</option>
    <option value="Iphone 12 Mini - Blue">Iphone 12 Mini - Blue</option> 
      <option value="Iphone 12 Pro - Green">Iphone 12 Pro - Green</option>
    <option value="Nike Sport Plus - Yellow">Nike Sport Plus - Yellow</option>
   <option value="Puma Shoes - Brown">Puma Shoes - Brown</option><option value="smart watch - -">smart watch - -</option>
</select>
    </td>
    <td class="d-print-none"><input type="number" id="total_qnty3" disabled=""></td>
   <td><input type="number" id="product_sp3" step=".01" required="" class="product-price"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="product_qnty3" name="product_qnty" required="" max="3" min="1" class="product-qnty"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="gst_perc3" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-gst"></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="tax_perc3" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-tax"></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="disc_perc3" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-disc"></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="final_price3" step=".01" required="" class="product-total"></td>
     </tr>
```

How do i get values and store it in JSON format ?

Comment: I made you a snippet. There was a `}` missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an array of productIDs and their quantities, you can use jQuery as follows

```js
$(function() {
  $("#print_invoice").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    const arr = $("#rowData [id^=product_id]")
      .map(function() {
        const $qnty = $(this).closest("tr").find("[id^=product_qnty]")
        return ({
          [$(this).attr("id")]: $(this).val(),
          [$qnty.attr("id")]: $qnty.val()
        })
      })
      .get();
    console.log(arr)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form id="invoice_data_process">


  <div class="row pt-1 px-2 py-2 border border-top-0">

    <div class="table-responsive px-2" style="overflow-x: hidden">

      <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered animated animatedFadeInRight fadeInRight" id="mainTable">

        <thead class="text-center" style="background-color: lightgrey">
          <tr>
            <th>Sr.</th>
            <th class="d-print-none d-none">id</th>
            <th>ID/SKU</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th class="d-print-none">Total Qty</th>
            <th>Price (₹)</th>
            <th>Qnty</th>
            <th>GST%</th>
            <th>Tax%</th>
            <th>Disc%</th>
            <th>Total (₹)</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="text-center" id="rowData">

          <tr class="items" id="item1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="d-none d-print-none"><input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="8"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="product_sku"></td>
            <td>
              <select id="products">
                <option>Select Product</option>
                <option value="Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple">Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple</option>
                <option value="Apple Watch Series 6 - Black">Apple Watch Series 6 - Black</option>
                <option value="Color check - Blue">Color check - Blue</option>
                <option value="Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey">Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey</option>
                <option value="iPad 5 - White">iPad 5 - White</option>
                <option value="Iphone 12 Mini - Blue">Iphone 12 Mini - Blue</option>
                <option value="Iphone 12 Pro - Green">Iphone 12 Pro - Green</option>
                <option value="Iphone 12 Pro - -">Iphone 12 Pro - -</option>
                <option value="Nike Sport Plus - Yellow">Nike Sport Plus - Yellow</option>
                <option value="Puma Shoes - Brown">Puma Shoes - Brown</option>
                <option value="smart watch - -">smart watch - -</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td class="d-print-none"><input type="number" id="total_qnty" disabled=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="product_sp" step=".01" required=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="product_qnty" name="product_qnty" required="" max="2" min="1"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="gst_perc" step=".01" min="0" max="100"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="tax_perc" step=".01" min="0" max="100"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="disc_perc" step=".01" min="0" max="100"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="final_price" step=".01" required=""></td>
          </tr>

          <!-- SECOND ROW OF INVOICE ---->

          <tr class="items" id="item1">
            <td>2</td>
            <td class="d-none d-print-none"><input type="hidden" id="product_id2" name="product_id" value="7" class="product-id"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="product_sku2"></td>
            <td>
              <select id="products2" class="product-selector">
                <option>Select Product</option>
                <option value="Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple">Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple</option>
                <option value="Apple Watch Series 6 - Black">Apple Watch Series 6 - Black</option>
                <option value="Color check - Blue">Color check - Blue</option>
                <option value="Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey">Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey</option>
                <option value="Iphone 12 Mini - Blue">Iphone 12 Mini - Blue</option>
                <option value="Iphone 12 Pro - Green">Iphone 12 Pro - Green</option>
                <option value="Iphone 12 Pro - -">Iphone 12 Pro - -</option>
                <option value="Nike Sport Plus - Yellow">Nike Sport Plus - Yellow</option>
                <option value="Puma Shoes - Brown">Puma Shoes - Brown</option>
                <option value="smart watch - -">smart watch - -</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td class="d-print-none"><input type="number" id="total_qnty2" disabled=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="product_sp2" step=".01" required="" class="product-price"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="product_qnty2" name="product_qnty" required="" max="38" min="1" class="product-qnty"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="gst_perc2" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-gst"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="tax_perc2" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-tax"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="disc_perc2" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-disc"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="final_price2" step=".01" required="" class="product-total"></td>
          </tr>

          <!---THIRD ROW OF INVOICE --->

          <tr class="items" id="item1">
            <td>3</td>
            <td class="d-none d-print-none"><input type="hidden" id="product_id3" name="product_id" value="35" class="product-id"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="product_sku3"></td>
            <td>
              <select id="products3" class="product-selector">
                <option>Select Product</option>
                <option value="Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple">Apple Watch Series 3 - Purple</option>
                <option value="Apple Watch Series 6 - Black">Apple Watch Series 6 - Black</option>
                <option value="Color check - Blue">Color check - Blue</option>
                <option value="Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey">Gucci sport Bag pro plus new demo - Grey</option>
                <option value="Iphone 12 Mini - Blue">Iphone 12 Mini - Blue</option>
                <option value="Iphone 12 Pro - Green">Iphone 12 Pro - Green</option>
                <option value="Nike Sport Plus - Yellow">Nike Sport Plus - Yellow</option>
                <option value="Puma Shoes - Brown">Puma Shoes - Brown</option>
                <option value="smart watch - -">smart watch - -</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td class="d-print-none"><input type="number" id="total_qnty3" disabled=""></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="product_sp3" step=".01" required="" class="product-price"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="product_qnty3" name="product_qnty" required="" max="3" min="1" class="product-qnty"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="gst_perc3" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-gst"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="tax_perc3" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-tax"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="disc_perc3" step=".01" min="0" max="100" class="product-disc"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="final_price3" step=".01" required="" class="product-total"></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>

  </div>


  </div>

  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkInvoice" value="1" class="d-print-none" />
    <label for="checkInvoice" class="text-danger d-print-none"><small>I have reviewed & checked the Invoice data for printing</small></label>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm d-print-none" type="submit" id="print_invoice">Process & Print Invoice</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hidden elements were styled because i copy pasted below input element, code is left to get cleaned

Comment: I have populated the select element, total_qnty, product_qnty & product_price by API. Hence there is no "value" attribute. Also there is "Add Row" to fill out more products. hence there are multiple rows from which i need values

Comment: it says : Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: If you have multiple rows you can't use something like `id="product_sp"`. Ids have to be unique.

Comment: Yes, every assigned id is unique, unique assignment is done with for loop

Comment: I have given "name" to fields that i require data of.

Comment: I want to deduct the product qnty by using product id, hence on submit the array will be passed to controller and window.print() will be triggered to print the invoice

Comment: thanks @mplungjan for your help, i am trying on both these solutions

Comment: Please see update. It is what you asked for in the comment you just deleted

Comment: @mplungjan it shows me this  : (2) [{…}, {…}]

Comment: @mplungjan I have used your given solution, its says : "Cannot read property 'value' of null" and shows URL with filled values like in the above comment.

When I inspect element on product_id, there it shows value="" but in product_qnty it does not show value attribute. But both shows its actual value/data when i do "document.getElementById('product_id')" & "document.getElementById('product_qnty')" in console window

Comment: I have id and name both

Comment: And you spell it `name="product_qnty"`

Comment: I have used like this:

`<td><input type="number" id="product_id" name="product_id" required></td>
<td><input type="number" id="product_qnty" name="product_qnty" required></td>`

Comment: @mplungjan I have updated my OP, please check it out.
I also want to inform you that element ids for first row in this dynamic table is assigned as 
eg. id= "product_qnty" ( for 1st row )
     id= "product_qnty2" (from 2nd row onwards)
     id= "product_qnty3" (and so on till nth row)  
And for all those mentioned input elements class is also applied for other functionality using for loops

Comment: Those all ids and classes applied are important for different functionalities like calculations, row population etc. Here "name" attribute is only applied for the extraction of data (i mean for your code)

Comment: sorry about that.. @mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan What did you change in your post ?

Comment: As i see in your code, you have mentioned "value= product 1" ..... in every input field.
Instead can we work with ids, because i have serialized ids for every row as mentioned in above comment. i have cleaned up my html code (removed style)

Comment: it gives me same error even if i change from = to ^=

Comment: @mplungjan with lots of efforts i updated my code with cleaned html, have a look

Comment: I have added your changes in JS but unfortunately same error along with the URL. May be my updated code may help you understand better. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sorry to say, but still same error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
create_invoice?product_id=19&product_qnty=12&product_id=8&product_qnty=2

Navigated to http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_invoice?product_id=8&product_qnty=2&product_id=3&product_qnty=15

Comment: @mplungjan I have used "j" instead of "i", as per my code, is it right ?
cellVal = oCells[j].querySelector("input").value || oCells[j].querySelector("select").value || 0; in for loop (code mentioned in OP)

Comment: Hi @mplungjan i have removed the for loop in function InvoiceDataProcess( ), instead i have just added your given function InvoiceDataProcess( ) of your post. Now there is no value-null error but it shows like this -   (2) [{…}, {…}] and when I expand it, it just gives me an "info" symbol beside it which says - "This value was evaluated on first expanding.It may have changed since then." And also below gives the same URL with its values as we discussed in above comments.

Comment: Its already in chrome. I will share a picture in OP.

Comment: Check the console image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jNey.png

Comment: Everything is in place, I have shared you complete code related to it along with html. IDs used has also been shared. When i enter one row it shows- [{…} and if i enter 2 rows it shows [{…} [{…}

Comment: Util.js:179 : new TypeError('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap\'s JavaScript.')

Comment: Look at this output i have added your code (removed onclick ) https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW5YZ.png

Comment: Looks correct to me if product_id is 22 and product_id2 is  7

Comment: Yep great that working, thanks for all your help. The problem was that i was looking for header file where all js and css were placed properly. But i forgot that i prepared a seperate js/css for this file and forgot to see its <head>.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

There have been vast improvements over the years to how JavaScript can manage and update the DOM, and in your case, fetch form *values*.

Here I select the table with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), and then I use that element to select the input, select, and textarea elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (you can add more form elements to that list if you need to).

You can then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over those elements and return their values.

```js
// Get the table
const table = document.querySelector('table');

// Now find all the form elements within the table
const elements = table.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');

// Handle the form submission
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {

  // We can't use `map` directly on a nodelist from querySelectorAll
  // so we need to change it to a proper array
  // Here we're iterating over the elements and creating a new
  // array of objects with the element name as the key,
  // and the value as, well, the value
  const data = Array.from(elements).map(el => ({ [el.name]: el.value }));

  // Stringify the data!
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="name" placeholder="Some text" type="text" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>
        <select name="products">
          <option selected disabled>Select Product</option>
          <option>Bob</option>
          <option>Steve</option>
          <option>Doris</option>
        </select>
      </td></tr>
      <tr><td><input name="number" type="number" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><textarea name="area"></textarea></td></tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: (In Inspect element) Values are visible but in url format like this :

Navigated to http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_invoice?product_id=1&product_list=Apple+Watch+Series+6+-+Black&product_sp=35000.39&product_qnty=2&product_id=1&product_list=Iphone+12+Pro+-+-&product_sp=95000&product_qnty=2
What do i do now ?

Comment: How to extract values from given URL  : Navigated to http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_invoice?product_id=1&product_list=Apple+Watch+Series+6+-+Black&product_sp=35000.39&product_qnty=2&product_id=1&product_list=Iphone+12+Pro+-+-&product_sp=95000&product_qnty=2

Comment: @mplungjan maybe just accept that someone equally experienced as you at JS came up with a similar answer. Even you suggested that the OP should use a name attribute, My answers tend to be illustrative to try and teach new programmers better ways of coding. I'm not in it just for the reputation.

Comment: am looking for solution to extract the URL with multiple keys and its values to form an array like this: { product_id : 1 product_qnty : 7 } { product_id : 3 product_qnty : 9 } please give me solution for this @Andy